# Can't detect collision between a rectangle and a circle in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, collision-detection, collision, p5.js

```js
var rectx = 287.5;
var recty = 460;
var rectx2 = 287.5
var recty2 = 0
var rectwidth = 100
var rectheight = 25
//ball vars
var xBall = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 50;
var yBall = 50;
var diameter = 75;
var xBallChange = 5;
var yBallChange = 5;
//Misc
var started = false;
var score = 0;
var score2 = 0;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    
    //main commands
    xBall += xBallChange;
    yBall += yBallChange;
    if (xBall < diameter/2 || xBall > windowWidth - 0.5*diameter) {
        xBallChange *= -1;
    }
    if (yBall < diameter/2 || yBall > windowHeight - diameter) {
        yBallChange *= -1;
    }

    if ((xBall > rectx && xBall < rectx + rectwidth) && (yBall + (diameter/2) >= recty)) {
        xBallChange *= -1;
        yBallChange *= -1;
        score++;
    }

    //Player 1
    fill (0,255,255);
    noStroke();
    rect(rectx,recty,rectwidth,rectheight);
    //Player 2
    fill(0,255,255)
    noStroke()
    rect(rectx2,recty2,rectwidth,rectheight);
    //The ball
    fill (255,255,0);
    noStroke();  
    ellipse(xBall,yBall,75,75)
    // The partition
    fill(148,0,211)
    noStroke()
    rect(0,257,750,1)
}

function keyPressed() {
    //Player 1 Input
    if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
        rectx -= 50;
    } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
        rectx += 50;
    }
    //Player 2 Input
    if (keyCode === 65) {
        rectx2 -= 50;
    } else if (keyCode === 68) {
        rectx2 += 50;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

This is my code. I want the circle/ball to reflect off the second rectangle placed on top. Please help me with the appropriate commands required for this program. I have tried many possibilities and have got the first rectangle to work as I want(the circle/ball reflects off the rectangle). I am trying to make the pong game for two people to play locally. THank you for helping me.

Comment: Your code checks the collisions between (`xball`,`yball`) and (`rectx`,`recty`) but you don't do the check against (`rectx2`,`recty2`) did you just forgot to write this code? (Also using [`p5.Vector`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) to store your positions and acceleration would be much easier and handle a lot of `x` and `y` variables as you currently do. Also also maybe you want to have a look at [p5 play](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) to handle collisions in this kind of simple programs.

Answer (score 1):

If the ball hits the paddle, then only invert the y component of the direction vector of the ball to reflect the ball on the inner side of the paddle. Correct the position of the ball so that it touches the paddle:

```js
if (xBall > rectx && xBall < rectx + rectwidth && yBall + diameter/2 >= recty) {
    yBallChange *= -1;
    yBall = recty - diameter/2;
    score++;
}
```

This is only an approximation of course, the reflection at the corners is incorrect and the ball does not bounce on the left or right edge of the paddle, but it is a good starting point.

Implement a similar algorithm for the 2nd paddle:

```js
if (xBall > rectx2 && xBall < rectx2 + rectwidth && yBall - diameter/2 < recty2+rectheight) {
    yBallChange *= -1;
    yBall = recty2 + rectheight + diameter/2;
    score2++;
}
```

Complete example:

```js
//Rect vars  
var rectx = 287.5;
var recty = 460;
var rectx2 = 287.5
var recty2 = 0
var rectwidth = 100
var rectheight = 25
//ball vars
var xBall = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 50;
var yBall = 50;
var diameter = 75;
var xBallChange = 5;
var yBallChange = 5;
//Misc
var started = false;
var score = 0;
var score2 = 0;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(750, 485);
}


function draw() {
    background(0);
    
    //main commands
    xBall += xBallChange;
    yBall += yBallChange;
    if (xBall < diameter/2 || xBall > width - diameter/2) {
        xBallChange *= -1;
    }
    if (yBall < diameter/2 || yBall > height - diameter/2) {
        yBallChange *= -1;
    }

    if (xBall > rectx && xBall < rectx + rectwidth && yBall + diameter/2 >= recty) {
        yBallChange *= -1;
        yBall = recty - diameter/2;
        score++;
    }

    if (xBall > rectx2 && xBall < rectx2 + rectwidth && yBall - diameter/2 < recty2+rectheight) {
        yBallChange *= -1;
        yBall = recty2 + rectheight + diameter/2;
        score2++;
    }

    //Player 1
    fill (0,255,255);
    noStroke();
    rect(rectx,recty,rectwidth,rectheight);
    //Player 2
    fill(0,255,255)
    noStroke()
    rect(rectx2,recty2,rectwidth,rectheight);
    //The ball
    fill (255,255,0);
    noStroke();  
    ellipse(xBall,yBall,75,75)
    // The partition
    fill(148,0,211)
    noStroke()
    rect(0,257,750,1)
}

function keyPressed() {
    //Player 1 Input
    if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
        rectx -= 50;
    } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
        rectx += 50;
    }
    //Player 2 Input
    if (keyCode === 65) {
        rectx2 -= 50;
    } else if (keyCode === 68) {
        rectx2 += 50;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```